# Convert json object from array of objects to string in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I have a json like this:

```
 [ {"numbers":["1","2","3","4"], 
    "city":"Tokio", 
    "color":"blue", 
   }, 

   {"numbers":["5","6","7","8"],
    "city":"Tokio",
     "color":"green", 
   }, 
    ......... 
 ]
```

and i need to convert to another json with javascript like this:

```
[ {"numbers":"1,2,3,4", 
    "city":"Tokio", 
    "color":"blue", 
   }, 

   {"numbers":"5,6,7,8",
    "city":"Tokio",
     "color":"blue", 
   }, 
    ......... 
 ]
```

so, i need to convert the array of numbers in a string, any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have, is not JSON, either is the code what you want to get.

Comment: json parse followed by arr.join()

Comment: @guilieen , I have question second answer as per your comment. Please, have look and if it is solving your problem then accept answer and upvote it. it will help to other people

Comment: @AnaSvitlica and Pramod Kharade 
both answers are correct, but I am afraid that I can only choose one and I keep the oldest one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an array use this:

```js
const jsonObjArray = [
  {
         "numbers":["1","2","3","4"],
         "city":"Tokio",
         "color":"blue"
  },
  {
         "numbers":["1","2","3","4"],
         "city":"New York",
         "color":"red"
  },
  {
         "numbers":["1","2","3","4"],
         "city":"Rome",
         "color":"green"
  }
]

const result = [];
jsonObjArray.map( item => {
  const numbers = item["numbers"];
  let numbersAsString = numbers.join(",");
  result.push({...item, numbers: numbersAsString});
});
    
console.log(result)
```

Comment: @AnaSvitlica Asker want to encode `JSON` after string conversion from array, your is incomplete please edit your answer to avoid downvotes. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1:**

```js
const data ={"numbers":["1","2","3","4"],
 "city":"Tokio",
 "color":"blue",
};
let modifyResult={}
for (const key in data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      
      if(key==="numbers"){
      
      modifyResult[key]= data["numbers"].join(", ");
      
      }else{
      modifyResult[key]= data[key];
      }
        
        
      }
    }
    console.log("Final:",modifyResult);
```

Hope, this will solve your problem.

OutPut Screen-Shot:

[image]

**Answer 2:**

As per your comment you want to transform the array of object with their key, So I am providing Second answer

```js
const data = [ {"numbers":["1","2","3","4"], "city":"Tokio", "color":"blue", }, {"numbers":["5","6","7","8"], "city":"Tokio", "color":"green", }];

const finalresult = data.map(item => {
    letcontainer = {};
    container = {...item};
    container.numbers = item.numbers.join(", ");

    return container;
})

console.log(finalresult);
```

OutPut Screen-shot:

[image]

Comment: yes it works, but i forget that my json is an array also... i think is only add a for loop, but could be the best solution? this is mi json:

[  {"numbers":["1","2","3","4"],
    "city":"Tokio",
    "color":"blue",
   },
   {"numbers":["5","6","7","8"],
    "city":"Tokio",
    "color":"green",
   },
   .........
]

Comment: In question, you have provide as object and here in comment array of object. you need to correct your question.